# Did VentureStar technology lead anywhere?

Tags: rockets, nasa, ssto, lockheed-martin, canceled-project

[VentureStar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VentureStar) seemed to make a bit of progress before being cancelled in 2001. Did any of the technology developed for this program lead anywhere? For example, its aerospike engines or high-tech fuel tanks?

It seems that pretty much all rocket technology after then didn't deviate too far from previous generations.

Comment: Down a giant rat hole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many lessons learned from that activity are being applied to [ongoing composite tank work](http://www.nasa.gov/press/2013/july/nasa-tests-game-changing-composite-cryogenic-fuel-tank/) at NASA.